# Countdown timer for test engine in php

Tags: javascript, php, time, countdowntimer

Hello I am trying to add countdown timer in my test engine. But I am unable to display that. If I am adding script in php page than its working but reloading and starting again. but if i am keeping java script file separate to avoid reload than unable to display timer. I am Adding code please suggest me suitable ans.Html and js are in separate file.

```
<script>
    //define your time in second
    var c=120;
    var t;
    timedCount();

    function timedCount() {
        var hours = parseInt( c / 3600 ) % 24;
        var minutes = parseInt( c / 60 ) % 60;
        var seconds = c % 60;

        var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);

        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=result;

        if(c == 0 ) {
            //setConfirmUnload(false);
            //$("#quiz_form").submit();
            window.location="result.php?td=$tid";
        }
        c = c - 1;
        t = setTimeout(function() {
            timedCount()
        },
        1000);
    }
</script>

//html
<div class='col-md-12 sub_top'>
    <h4 style="color:#FF0000" align="center">
        Time Remaining : <span id='timer'></span>
    </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element (   document.getElementById("timer") )you were trying to find wasn’t in the DOM when the script ran.

**Solution 1**

To fix this you can execute the code on [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event

```
   window.onload = function(){
              timedCount();
    }
```

**Solution 2**

execute code on [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) (document ready )

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
              timedCount();
            }, false);
```

**Solution 3**

Move your script  just before the closing body tag.

Comment: problem with this solution is that each time i reload the page timer starts from beginning.That I don't want, actually its online test engine where after submission of each question page reloads for another question, timers also starts from beginning but don't want timer to reload.

Comment: you can pass the remaining time as GET parameter when you change the window location